# How can I pull 3 unique values from a single array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I need to pull multiple values from but I can't have any of those values repeat.

This is what I am doing now, but it does not discourage multiples of the same value.

My array is:

`$boom = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");`

And I am using 3 of this code to pull the values:

`echo $boom[array_rand($boom,1)];`

The end result in the context of the page looks like this - "1, 4, 3" (or any variation of the numbers...) But my issue is that I have a need for the script to pull 3 non-repeating values.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get unique values then use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to random the order. Then you can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the first three element and you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to output them as a comma separated string.

```
$a = array_unique(array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"));
shuffle($a);
$b = array_slice($a, 0, 3);
echo implode(',', $b);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/614894)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am trying the array with 18 values and instead of outputting 3, it's outputting all 18 in a random order. The code works fine when I cut the array down to 6 values. What's the limit for values in the array?

Comment: Minor bug on my part. See the updated code for the fix. The demo has been updated to show it working for 18 array values as well.

Comment: Awesome! Works good now. Why does adding that zero make a difference?

Comment: @D.JasonPayne if an answer solves your problem, please upvote and select it.

Comment: Sorry! I'm new! I don't know what to do! I upvoted and selected.